# Are there codeigniter controller sub-directory limits?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Greetings,

I've encountered a seemingly bizarre issue, and was wondering if anyone is able to shed a light.

I created a simple controller two levels down from the traditional /application/controllers/ directory and I'm seeing a CI-generated 404 when hitting said controller.

To elaborate, my directory structure is as follows:
**/ci/application/controllers/dir1/dir2/myfile.php**

The file itself has a simple function with an echo statement. When I move said file up one level such that it is located in:
**/ci/application/controllers/dir1/myfile.php**

It works.

I've tried changing the name of the "dir2" directory in the example above, the name of the controller, the names of the functions within the controller -- to no avail. I'm able to hit the same php file without going through the Code Igniter framework, and I'm on a Windows machine working normally so I can't imagine this to be a permissions-related issue.

I'm led to think that CI simply isn't willing to go into the controllers directory more than one level. **Is this possible, or am I missing something?**

Comment: What's the reasoning behind having it so many folders deep? That could potentially help with offering a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Out of the box", Codeigniter only supports a single level directory structure for Controllers.

[There are ways to extend the default Router class to enable this feature.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033226/are-there-codeigniter-controller-sub-directory-limits/5033258#5033258)

Answer (score 2):

Try this out: http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/

Basically, you need to override the default codeigniter router with your own MY_Router class